# How to get from Wroclaw airport to city center?

Tags: airport-transfer, poland, wroclaw

What are the options to get from Wroclaw airport (Ryanair flight) to city center? What's the cheapest option?

Comment: Just what I needed great question +1 and drinks for every body on the house!!!

Comment: What time do you land in Wroclaw? Is it one of those supercheap Ryanair flights that leave you stranded in the middle of nowhere at 3am, and the taxis and buses wont show up on the airport before 7? :)

Comment: Yes, it's supercheap, but not, we land at 2pm

Comment: @iHaveacomputer Here you are at least at real suburbs of Wroclaw, not the actually different city 25 km away like it happens often to Ryanair-hosting airports. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. city bus, line `406` - ticket 2.40 PLN (~0.56 €)
2. night bus, line `249` - ticket 2.80 PLN (~ 0.66 €)
3. taxi - less than 50 PLN (~ 12 €)

If you are taking `406` day bus and want to get to main market square, quit bus at "Renoma" stop and follow *Świdnicka* street.

If you want to get to train or bus station, quit bus at "Dworcowa" stop (the last one).

Answer (score 7):

Looks like bus is the primary (only) option, according to [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Wroclaw).  At least buses are cheap :)

- From the airport, bus 406 operates from the terminal building to central Wrocław between 5am and 11pm every 20 minutes ([schedule](http://www.um.wroc.pl/rozklady/przystanki/406_18_2.html)). There is also a night bus 249 ([schedule](http://www.um.wroc.pl/rozklady/przystanki/249_47_3.html)). The night bus will take approximately one hour to get to the city center (it will have a short break in the Jarnołtów district). If you are not sure how to get to your final destination in Wrocław by public transport, it might be helpful to use the [journey planner](http://wroclaw.jakdojade.pl/?locale=en). Single-ride tickets from Wroclaw Airport to the city center cost 2.40 PLN (or 1.20 PLN for students or ISIC/EURO 26 Holders).
- the alternative is to take a tax (less than 100 PLN)

Answer (score 3):

There's a video answering this question, showing the airport & giving some other information. Accurate 2016 https://youtu.be/g_oTTOARu-o