# Public transports from Prague to Wroclaw

Tags: trains, public-transport, buses, prague, wroclaw

Is there shuttle or train (other than Eurolines) from Prague to Wroclaw?

It doesn't matter if it's direct or not, but I couldn't find any link for booking the train.
I have to be in Wroclaw maximum at 4 o'clock,on 21st august, but Eurolines arrives too late.

Comment: releted: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/how-to-get-from-wroclaw-airport-to-city-center

Comment: Those are actually 2 questions. Are you interested only in trains (for any reason) or buses are also an option?

Comment: Do you specifically mean direct trains?  I find a connection with one change, in Pardubice.

Comment: @user7922 http://www.polskibus.com/en is not a train service but....

Answer (score 2):

[Deutsche Bahn website](http://www.bahn.de/p/view/index.shtml) finds a few connections, e.g.

```
Praha hl.n.      Mi, 21.08.13    ab 05:16       EX 521   Express-Zug
Pardubice hl.n.  Mi, 21.08.13    an  06:21    

 Wait time 10 Min.

Pardubice hl.n.  Mi, 21.08.13    ab 06:31       Sp 1915 R 1915   Eilzug
Wroclaw Glowny   Mi, 21.08.13    an  10:28
```

There doesn't seem to be any direct train though.